# Is it possible to split array in Gherkin to the next line

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

I have step where I am have String Array, something like this:

```
Then Drop-dow patient_breed contains ['Breed1', 'Breed2',.... Breed20']
```

I need to split this text on two lines. I know that in Gherkin there is expression """. I try something like this:

```
Then Drop-dow patient_breed contains ['Breed1',
"""
'Breed2',.... Breed20']
"""
```

It didn't help. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you gain by putting this string in your scenario. IMO all you are doing is making the scenario harder to read!

What do you lose by putting this string in your scenario?

Well first of all you now have to have at least two things the determine the exact contents of the string, the thing in the application that creates it and the hardcoded string in your scenario. So you are repeating yourself.

In addition you've increased the cost of change. Lets say we want our strings to change from 'Breedx' to 'Breed: x'. Now you have to change every scenario that looks at the drop down. This will take much much longer than changing the code.

So what can you do instead?

Change your scenario step so that it becomes `Then I should see the patient breeds` and delegate the HOW of the presentation of the breeds and even the sort of control that the breeds are presented in to something that is outside of Cucumber e.g. a helper method called by a step definition, or perhaps even something in your codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a datatable approach. You will have to add a `DataTable` argument in the stepdefinition.

```
Then Drop-dow patient_breed contains
'Breed1'
'Breed2'
...
...
...
'Breed20']
```

For a multiline approach try the below. In this you will have to add a `String` argument to the stepdefinition.

```
Then Drop-dow patient_breed contains
"""
  ['Breed1','Breed2',.... Breed20']
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

I would read the entire string and then split it using Java after it has been passed into the step. In order to keep my step as a one or two liner, I would use a helper method that I implemented myself.